# jQuery or Silverlight in situations where either will work?

Tags: jquery, silverlight

In the past I always advocated the use of jQuery instead of Flash whenever possible, mainly because of SEO concerns.

From what I understand Silverlight does not have the same issues with Search Engine Crawlers.  The more I use jQuery the more I love it, but I'm curious about how the pros and cons compare to those of Silverlight.

For situations where you can use either jQuery or Silverlight are there documented reasons for or against using either technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to keep in mind is that "jQuery" is not an independent technology we can really evaluate. It's just a bunch of JavaScript functions. Granted, they're fantastic JavaScript functions that make JavaScript remarkably easy to write, but to the browser (which doesn't care about "easy") they're just ordinary, unremarkable functions.

So your question is really "For situations where you can use either ***JavaScript*** or Silverlight are there documented reasons for or against using either technology?"

And that's a more straightforward question. Every mainstream browser in use today has support for JavaScript. Users can disable it, of course, but most do not, and the default setting on all popular browsers is to leave it on.

By contrast, Silverlight does not come preinstalled on most platforms, and cannot be installed on some (e.g., iOS devices). So even a user who is willing to enable Silverlight may still need to download and install it — more work than a lot of people are willing to undertake merely to view your website.

We cannot yet go so far as to say that JavaScript is universal, but it is as close to universal as any web-based client-side scripting language has ever come before.

Bottom line: ***never*** use a specialized technology (Flash, Silverlight, any browser plugin, et cetera) if you can accomplish the same goal with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. This is not to say other technologies have no place on the web, but if you're using them merely to replicate features the browser already has, you are narrowing your target audience for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

One disadvantage of using Silverlight is that a user needs to have that runtime installed on their machine. Worse, this may not be an option for people on certain classes of devices such as mobile phones, iPad/Pod, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am rather new in web development but my understanding is that Silverlight would not work on several platforms, e.g., the iphone or ipad. Its one of those Microsoft things and I dislike the fact that it requires a download. jQuery is more universal and works on all browsers without requiring install.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that there are some platforms that are not available for Silverlight.  So, if that is important to your situation do not use Silverlight.

If you are developing a public website and reaching everyone in the world is your goal, do not use Silverlight.  Doing so will limit your reach.  All of the other answers here appear to be predicated on that premise and within that narrowly focused scope they are correct.

However, when a rich user interface for an application is needed, the lowest common denominator approach of HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery **may** not be your best choice.

Remember that when the iPhone first became available the Apple story was that apps should be browser based.  Sounded great.  But the reality is that the native API provided capabilities that were not and are not available.  For that reason the app store was born.

The same is true with Silverlight.  There are capabilities available in Silverlight that do not exist in browser.  Those capabilities might give you the ability to create an experience in your app that you could not match in HTML.  Silverlight is a very good and productive development environment and it is the right choice in many situations.

My favorite illustration of this is Facebook.  Nearly everyone that has ever used a browser has visited the Facebook site.  All of the Facebook functionality is available on the HTML interface available there.  Yet nearly no one uses the Facebook browser interface on iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows Phone 7, or nearly any other platform.  Only on fullsize PC (Mac, Windows or Linux) is the browser interface used.  Even there, some of the native UI applications may dominate, but I do not know that for a fact.  They are certainly at the very least, popular.  The reason is obvious.  The user interface on these non-HTML apps is better.

Do not misunderstand, jQuery is great, and is often the right answer and a good one.  Even Microsoft abandoned their own Ajax framework and jumped on the jQuery bandwagon, and for good reason.  It is a good technology and is often used successfully.

But if you create an application using HTML as your interface you just might get run over by another app solving the same problem but providing a richer user interface.  Even if the other guy had to create more than one UI he could still be the winner.